# TypeError when Using API in Javascript

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I'm trying to make a Trivia Game using Open Trivia DB.
 What I want is to display only the questions in the `triviaQ` constant and I did that. The code works, it does what I want it to do BUT, when I refresh the page sometimes, this error shows up in the console: 
`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'question')` 
The error points to: `question_data.question` and underlines the question which doesn't make sense because it is a valid key from the API json. Plus, what confuses me even more is that it still displays the question even if there is an error and the error appears sometimes. Thank you in advance for your time!

Javascript Code:

```
const api_url = 'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&difficulty=easy&type=boolean'
const triviaQ = document.getElementById("triviaQuestion")
let question_data = ""

async function display() {
    const response = await fetch(api_url);
    const data = await response.json()
    for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
        question_data = data.results[randNum]
        triviaQ.innerHTML = question_data.question
    }
}

display()
```

Comment: The error means that `question_data` is `undefined`, therefore it doesn't have a `question` property, therefore it throws an error. Since you use `data.results[randNum]`, then it means that you get something out of bounds of the array, so `question_data` becomes `undefined` as a result.

Comment: Thank you! You are right, it went out of bounds so I made corrections and the error is gone! To think it was that easy. I appreciate it 